# issue with chef server installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chef-infra

I am trying to install chef server on linux Ubuntu by following guide on opscode website as it is.

Now the first error that I see on console while installing was:

```
Setting permissions for user "chef" in vhost "/chef" ...
...done.

Creating config file /etc/chef/solr.rb with new version
 * Starting chef-solr  chef-solr                                         [fail]
```

I looked  solr.log  inside var/log/chef/solr.log

```
[Wed, 02 May 2012 20:32:02 -0700] FATAL: Chef Solr is not installed or solr_home_path, solr_data_path, and solr_jetty_path are misconfigured.
[Wed, 02 May 2012 20:32:02 -0700] FATAL: Your current configuration is:
[Wed, 02 May 2012 20:32:02 -0700] FATAL: solr_home_path:  /var/chef/solr
[Wed, 02 May 2012 20:32:02 -0700] FATAL: solr_data_path:  /var/chef/solr/data
[Wed, 02 May 2012 20:32:02 -0700] FATAL: solr_jetty_path: /var/chef/solr-jetty
[Wed, 02 May 2012 20:32:02 -0700] FATAL: You can install Chef Solr using the chef-solr-installer script.
```

I have followed the tutorial as it is as given on http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Installing+Chef+Server+on+Debian+or+Ubuntu+using+Packages

What could be the issue? Looking at solr.log says " Chef Solr is not installed or solr_home_path, solr_data_path, and solr_jetty_path are misconfigured." I am a windows guy. How can I check if chef solr is installed or there is problem with path in linux?

Can there be any other issue?

Comment: why has someone votet for closing?

Comment: Did someone answer this question?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by doing the following

1. created /etc/chef/solr.rb

Containing the following:

- Base directory where solr is installed

`supportdir = "/srv/chef/support"`

- Solr Configuration Information

`solr_jetty_path File.join(supportdir, "solr", "jetty")`

`solr_data_path  File.join(supportdir, "solr", "data")`

`solr_home_path  File.join(supportdir, "solr", "home" )`

1. Then executed chef-solr-installer

If you are running solr in standalone jetty I think you need to change solr_jetty_path to point to your jetty installation location e.g. /usr/local/jetty. I can only confirm that after further experimentation

Hope that helps you slightly

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you added the wrong apt repository for your distribution.

```
deb http://apt.opscode.com/ <codename> main
```

Check this please.

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby 1.8, 
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-solr-10.16.2/lib/chef/solr/solr_installer.rb is missing

`require "fileutils"`